# Control 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ gridview ' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside the form IN ASP MASTER PAGE

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

this is pradeep . We have to create Master Pages. we have to add Default page instead of Master pages.

we have to apply the code . I am getting error like this

" Control 'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_ gridview ' of type 'GridView' must be placed inside the form"

here goes my content page

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">

</asp:Content>
```

here goes my master page

```
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server"   >
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the ContentPlaceholder is inside

```
<form runat="server">


</form>
```

Comment: in content place holder is uses in default page instead of Master pages. we does not use form tag in default page.

Comment: @user582977 - Can you post some markup please? It will make it easier to see what the situation is.

Comment: Hi, we have done same format. inside the form tag ,contenet place holder we will write gridview code still iam getting error.

Comment: @user582977 - Please paste your markup and codebehind here so we can look at it in full - its hard to try to fix it without seeing it all!

Answer (score 1):

A gridview must be placed in a server-side form.

```
<form id="frm" runat="server">
<asp:gridview />
</form>
```

That form can either reside on the content page, or it must surround the content placeholder on the master page. It must be one or the other - you can only have one server side form on a page.

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in your Code behind.

```
Public Overloads Overrides Sub VerifyRenderingInServerForm(ByVal control As Control)


End Sub
```